# Sudoku Java - Efficient way

Tags: java

I am programming a sudoku puzzle with each cell represented by a `JTextField`, for 81 `JTextField` objects in total. This arrangement leaves me wondering about how to efficiently clear the puzzle.

Right now I have this:

```
void clear() {
    t1.setText("");
    t2.setText("");
    t3.setText("");
    t4.setText("");
    t5.setText("");
    t6.setText("");
    t7.setText("");
    t8.setText("");
    t9.setText("");
    t10.setText("");
    t11.setText("");
    t12.setText("");
    t13.setText("");
    t14.setText("");
    t15.setText("");
         .
         .
    t81.setText("");
}
```

That's 81 `.setText()` calls. Is there a better way to clear my puzzle?

Comment: for loop, use a matrix/array

Comment: `Stream.of(t1,t2,...,t81).forEach(t -> t.setText(""));`

Comment: @aioobe I prefer `Stream.of(arrayOfJTextField).forEach(t -> t.setText(""))`.

Comment: If you have an `arrayOfJTextField` at hand, sure. (Though then I'd probably prefer `for (JTextField tf : arrayOfJTextField) tf.setText("");`.)

Comment: Since you're using `Swing` you could also work with `JTable` and a 2d array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `t1` ... `t81` declare them like this:

```
JTextField[][] textField = new JTextField[9][9];
```

Refer to them like `textField[2][2]` where this is the *third* row and *third* column (`[0]` is the first, remember!). Because this is a `JTextField` I assume you are making UI, so for `textField[i][j]` `i` and `j` could be rows/columns depending on how you put them on the screen.

To clear them all use a for loop. This is easy, so instead of answering this part I prepared a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+iterate+over+2d+array+in+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) for you.

Comment: @aioobe `for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < textField.length; i++) { while (j < textField[i].length) { ...; j++; } j = 0; }` Check mate ;P

Comment: You don't even need a second loop. But I wouldn't call that "clean code".

Comment: @Tom don't think I think my comment was clean, I was just proving a point.

Comment: I know and no, I wouldn't call that "clean" either :P :D.

Comment: @CaptainMan, well, `for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++) tf[i/9][i%9].setText("");`